# Shopify BUY SDK : Maintain cart items between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, shopify

This is the first app I am developing involving [Shopify's BUY SDK](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios) and cannot seem to figure the best way to maintain cart items across view controllers. If anyone has any experience with the mobile buy api for Shopify I would really appreciate any ideas on how this can be achieved.

For example, I have `ShopViewController.swift` which is a generic browse view showing several items for sale. Upon clicking an item, `BUYProductViewController.m` is presented displaying the item and its different variants. Upon clicking "Add to Cart" it will add that variant to the cart and dismiss `BUYProductViewController.m`. My issue lay in getting that newly added item back to `ShopViewController.swift`.

As I mentioned, any help would greatly be appreciated and thank you for taking the time to read my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one BUYCart property in AppDelegate and assign Domain, App_Id and API_key in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

self.client = [[BUYClient alloc] initWithShopDomain:SHOP_DOMAIN
                                             apiKey:API_KEY
                                              appId:APP_ID];

return YES;
}
```

Now use BUYCart property in to cart. I have just complete one demo of Shopify.

Comment: Hello Bro, Plz Help me I want to add Product in Cart..Plz Share your demo link... I am new in iOS and Shopify API. So, Plz Help me.

Comment: Hello Bhai...Help me plz ?

Comment: I want to implement Login and Registration ...So, First need this,  SHOP_DOMAIN , API_KEY , APP_ID right ?

Comment: You can get 
'SHOP_DOMAIN'
'API_KEY'
'APP_ID' from Shopify web site. You need to create your self.

Comment: But, Client ne website Develop kar k rakhi he or me ussi ek webservice ka use kar raha hu... to ye credencials uske pass hi honge ki meri side se kuch karna padega ?

Comment: Yes... You need to talk with Client and get credential of Shopify.

Comment: Bro, I am Working on recoverPassword API, getting some error plz help me.
My Code is,==>  
[self.client recoverPasswordForCustomer:txtEmail.text callback:^(BUYStatus status, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(@"NO ERROR");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Failed to create customer: %@", error.userInfo);
        }
    }];
I am getting this error,
Error Domain=BUYShopifyErrorDomain Code=404 "(null)"

Failed to create customer: {
}